# Ease Function always return beginning value when I set the changeInValue to 0

Tags: javascript

```
// t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
easeOutSine: (t, b, c, d) => c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
```

Obviously, if the parameter of 'c' is 0, that will always return the begining value, so what should I do if I just want change the value to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Call the function with `c` (change in value) equal to `-b` (the negative of the beginning value.)